# Traefik problem setting up an MQTT broker + TLS + LETSENCRYPT certificate

Tags: docker, mqtt, traefik, lets-encrypt, emqx

I have been trying to get my mqtt + TLS broker behind Traefik to work for hours but without convincing results.

The broker's administration web server works perfectly in https with letsencrypt but I can't produce the equivalent with the MQTT connection on port 8883

Could someone please help me?

Here is my setup

```
version: '3.4'
services:

  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:${TRAEFIK_VERSION}
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
    - 80:80
    - 443:443
    - 8883:8883
    command:
    - --log.level=DEBUG
    - --providers.docker=true
    - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false


    # Entrypoints
    - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
    - --entrypoints.webSecure.address=:443
    - --entrypoints.mqtt.address=:8883


    # Redirect http to https
    - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.to=webSecure
    - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.scheme=https


    # Let's encrypt configuration
    - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.email=contact@hexa-ai.fr
    - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json
    - --certificatesresolvers.le.acme.tlschallenge=true

    volumes:
    - v_traefik:/letsencrypt
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

   emqx-service:
    image: emqx/emqx:${EMQX_VERSION}
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - EMQX_LOADED_PLUGINS="emqx_recon,emqx_retainer,emqx_management,emqx_dashboard,emqx_auth_http"
      - EMQX_AUTH__HTTP__AUTH_REQ__URL=${EMQX_AUTH__HTTP__AUTH_REQ__URL}
      - EMQX_AUTH__HTTP__AUTH_REQ__PARAMS=clientId=%c,username=%u,password=%P
      - EMQX_AUTH__HTTP__ACL_REQ__URL=${EMQX_AUTH__HTTP__ACL_REQ__URL}
      - EMQX_AUTH__HTTP__ACL_REQ__PARAMS=access=%A,username=%u,clientId=%c,ipaddr=%a,topic=%t,mountpoint=%m
      - EMQX_ZONE__EXTERNAL__PUBLISH_LIMIT=${EMQX_ZONE__EXTERNAL__PUBLISH_LIMIT}
      - EMQX_MQTT__MAX_PACKET_SIZE=10MB
    volumes:
      - v_emqx-data:/opt/emqx/data
      - v_emqx-etc:/opt/emqx/etc
      - v_emqx-log:/opt/emqx/log
    #ports:
     # - 8883:8883
     # - 3000:18083
    labels:
    - "traefik.enable=true"

    # - "traefik.http.routers.emqx-service.rule=Host(`mqtt.hexa-data.fr`)"
    # - "traefik.http.routers.emqx-service.tls.certresolver=le"
    # - "traefik.http.services.emqx-service.loadbalancer.server.port=18083"

     - "traefik.tcp.routers.emqx-service.rule=HostSNI(`*`)"
     - "traefik.tcp.routers.emqx-service.tls.certresolver=le"
     - "traefik.tcp.services.emqx-service.loadbalancer.server.port=8883"


    # Entrypoints
     - "traefik.tcp.routers.emqx-service.entrypoints=mqtt"
    #- "traefik.http.routers.emqx-service.entrypoints=webSecure"


    extra_hosts:
    - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

***Server logs***

```
time="2022-09-13T10:04:02Z" level=debug msg="Handling connection from 91.164.235.89:38383"
time="2022-09-13T10:04:06Z" level=debug msg="Handling connection from 91.164.235.89:33834"
time="2022-09-13T10:04:06Z" level=error msg="Error during connection: readfrom tcp 172.19.0.16:44948->172.19.0.15:8883: remote error: tls: expired certificate"
time="2022-09-13T10:04:06Z" level=debug msg="Error while terminating connection: tls: CloseWrite called before handshake complete"
time="2022-09-13T10:04:11Z" level=debug msg="Handling connection from 82.64.242.74:52648"
time="2022-09-13T10:04:11Z" level=debug msg="Handling connection from 91.164.235.89:45091"
time="2022-09-13T10:04:17Z" level=debug msg="Handling connection from 91.164.235.89:40677"
time="2022-09-13T10:04:21Z" level=debug msg="Handling connection from 91.164.235.89:33836"
time="2022-09-13T10:04:21Z" level=error msg="Error during connection: readfrom tcp 172.19.0.16:44972->172.19.0.15:8883: remote error: tls: expired certificate"
time="2022-09-13T10:04:21Z" level=debug msg="Error while terminating connection: tls: CloseWrite called before handshake complete"
time="2022-09-13T10:04:26Z" level=debug msg="Handling connection from 82.64.242.74:52710"
time="2022-09-13T10:04:26Z" level=debug msg="Error while setting deadline: set tcp 172.19.0.16:44976: use of closed network connection"
time="2022-09-13T10:04:26Z" level=debug msg="Handling connection from 91.164.235.89:37076"
time="2022-09-13T10:04:33Z" level=debug msg="Handling connection from 91.164.235.89:47424"
time="2022-09-13T10:04:36Z" level=debug msg="Handling connection from 91.164.235.89:33838"
time="2022-09-13T10:04:36Z" level=error msg="Error during connection: readfrom tcp 172.19.0.16:44990->172.19.0.15:8883: remote error: tls: expired certificate"
time="2022-09-13T10:04:36Z" level=debug msg="Error while terminating connection: tls: CloseWrite called before handshake complete"
time="2022-09-13T10:04:41Z" level=debug msg="Handling connection from 82.64.242.74:50496"
time="2022-09-13T10:04:42Z" level=debug msg="Handling connection from 91.164.235.89:45524"
time="2022-09-13T10:04:48Z" level=debug msg="Handling connection from 91.164.235.89:43400"
time="2022-09-13T10:04:51Z" level=debug msg="Handling connection from 91.164.235.89:33840"
time="2022-09-13T10:04:51Z" level=error msg="Error during connection: readfrom tcp 172.19.0.16:45010->172.19.0.15:8883: remote error: tls: expired certificate"
time="2022-09-13T10:04:51Z" level=debug msg="Error while terminating connection: tls: CloseWrite called before handshake complete"
time="2022-09-13T10:04:54Z" level=debug msg="Handling connection from 91.164.235.89:41826"
time="2022-09-13T10:04:55Z" level=debug msg="Handling connection from 91.164.235.89:38537"
time="2022-09-13T10:04:56Z" level=debug msg="Error while setting deadline: set tcp 172.19.0.16:45016: use of closed network connection"
time="2022-09-13T10:04:56Z" level=debug msg="Handling connection from 82.64.242.74:46692"
time="2022-09-13T10:04:56Z" level=debug msg="Error while setting deadline: set tcp 172.19.0.16:45018: use of closed network connection"
time="2022-09-13T10:04:57Z" level=debug msg="Handling connection from 91.164.235.89:37987"
```

***Client conf***

[image: Client conf]

***Client logs***

```
[2022-09-13 12:04:56] [INFO] MQTTX client with ID 1fa93978-f254-438e-bc39-e2830403351f assigned
[2022-09-13 12:04:56] [INFO] Connect client PFC2004G, MQTT/SSL connection: mqtts://mqtt.hexa-data.fr:8883
[2022-09-13 12:04:56] [INFO] PFC2004G connect close, MQTT.js onClose trigger
```

Comment: Edit the question to show how you are testing the MQTT connection and any information from the client e.g. errors. Will also be worth looking at the broker logs

Answer (score 1):

The important part of the log would appear to be this part from server.log

```
time="2022-09-13T10:04:06Z" level=error msg="Error during connection: readfrom tcp 172.19.0.16:44948->172.19.0.15:8883: remote error: tls: expired certificate"
```

This implies the client has closed the connection to the broker because the certificate presented has expired.

I would first check the time/timezone for the server and the client.

Also I'm not clear how you've set the hostname (or domain, since it's set up as a wildcard hostname) the for LetsEncrypt certificate for the MQTT connection.

I would use something like `openssl s_client` to check what certificate is being presented

```
openssl s_client -connect mqtt.hexa-data.fr:8883
```